# How do I focus an "urgent" application?

Tags: 11.10, compiz, window-manager, shortcut-keys

Sometimes applications will wiggle in the launcher and have a blue triangle. (See compiz config settings for Unity.)

How can I set a keyboard command to bring that application to the front in Ubuntu 11.10? I had it set in 11.04, but I don't remember how.

This is useful when programs open in the background or if you activate them from another app. (I have an alias to send files to a single gvim instance from Terminal instead of opening them in their own window. When gvim gets the file, it wiggles but doesn't gain focus.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `compiz-plugins-extra` package installed (which isn't in the default install), there's an "Extra WM Actions" that has a "activate demanding attention window" keybinding.

Comment: unfortunately I couldnt bind my 4th mouse button, so I bound the before useless PAUSE key, thx! :)

Answer (score 2):

I found this [**answer**](http://www.tuxgarage.com/2011/08/auto-raise-chat-and-other-windows.html) helpful too.

It's not a hotkey, but it helps raise items to the foreground automatically when urgent.

In particular, I found this helped after a recent update when Ubuntu was failing to cycle windows correctly when using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.